# Having trouble restarting the engine after stalling it while learning to drive manual

Tags: nissan, manual-transmission, stall, frontier

I'm learning to drive a manual in a 2010 Frontier SE KC, with a 4.0 and a 6-speed. It has 61k miles. As expected, there's a learning curve to driving stick, and I occasionally find myself killing the engine at launch, sometimes more than once before getting the shift right.

One thing I've noticed is that a few times, the engine won't immediately restart. I've got the clutch down to the floor, the shifter is in neutral, and I'll turn the key. The truck will go into accessory but not crank. If I wait a while (10-30 seconds) and try again, it'll crank back up again. The AC is on, for what it's worth.

I checked the ECM with a Bluetooth OBD2 adapter and Torque Pro on an Android tablet; nothing was found except an evap problem. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Thats not normal behavior - it may actually be linked to the evap issue Torque showed, can you post the code it gave?

Comment: What do you mean by *The truck will go into accessory but not crank* ?

Comment: @David the dash lights up, but the starter doesn't turn over to start the engine. If I wait 10-30 seconds, it'll crank and the engine will start.

Comment: What we all call the "ignition switch" is actually a mechanical lock operated by a key. With the right key, the lock turns and itself then operates the ignition switch, a multi-position electrical switch located just behind the mechanical lock. The truck's symptoms suggest either a) a fault in the electrical switch or its wiring, so that while the key is turned to "start," the electrical switch doesn't always rotate into the "start" position, or b) a mechanical fault between the mechanical lock and the electrical switch.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a failing neutral safety switch, either on the shifter, the clutch pedal, or both.

Comment: @David the only issue I have with this idea is that the condition only occurs when the engine has been stalled. This does not occur when starting the vehicle cold. Wouldn't an ignition switch issue happen all the time or under a wider range of conditions?

Comment: @the_storyteller would a neutral safety switch issue be a realistic possibility on a vehicle with under 65k miles? Wouldn't it cause more interference in driving than just occurring after stalls, like when the vehicle has a cold start?

Comment: I don't know about the Frontier, but on my (European) car if you stall the engine, the ignition switch is (obviously) still in the "on" position, but you can't operate the starter unless you first turn it to OFF and back on again. This is a side effect of a safety lock against operating the starter while the engine is already running. Maybe your Nissan is the same? (Since my car is a European design, there is NO "neutral safety switch" interlock with the gearbox or clutch).

Comment: Does the non-start condition occur when the engine is turned off using the ignition switch, then re-started right away while still warm, and not re-started from cold?

Comment: @David I'll do that test when I get home tonight, and come back with the result

Comment: @David, could not reproduce behavior. I'm getting better at shifts, so the stalls are becoming less frequent. However, I did stall multiple times in a row trying to back out of my driveway, and even then, no issue getting the engine to start. 

Could it just be that there was too much drain on the battery in too short a time? I was stalling out multiple times from stopped, trying to start again. That's a lot of starter use...